# ApiGility - Returning custom collections

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

My goal is to return a custom collection for a `findAll()` query and to deliver this to HAL in order to ensure that its `_links` are formatted correctly. I originally thought I would simply do this programmatically however this seems to be the wrong way of doing this.

The problem I face is that the data I require is not from a single table, but rather from multiple tables (joins) and I am unable to work out how to do this properly.

I have the following entities:

**Stone entity**: A standard table with a join to some attributes that I would like to return in my feed

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Stone\Entity\StAttribute")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="st_stone_attribute",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="stone_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     *
     * @var Collection
     * @access private
     */
    private $attribute;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

etc...
```

The attribute entity is a standard table:

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
```

**My resource calls:**

```
public function fetchAll($params = array())
    {
        return $this->stoneMapper->fetchAll();
    }
```

**My mapper file:**

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $qb   = $this->stoneRepository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.state=:state')
        ->setParameter('state' , 1 );

    $adapter    = new DoctrineAdapter( new ORMPaginator( $qb ) );
    $collection = new StoneCollection($adapter);

    return $collection;
}
```

**My collection**

```
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

class StoneCollection extends Paginator
{

}
```

Screen shot of the results here: http://screencast.com/t/vgm34s92dsk2

As you can see from the screen shot "attribute" and other similar fields are not being populated...

So my question is this: how do I ensure that the join tables are populated in the feed?

Comment: hey you got any solution for this?

Comment: @JimitShah I answered the question. It might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch join your associations. You can read on this in the Doctrine 2 documentation **[here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)**.

In your case it would look as follows:

```
$qb = $this->stoneRepository->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->addSelect('a')
    ->leftJoin('s.attribute', 'a')
    ->where('s.state = :state')
    ->setParameter('state' , 1 );
```

It will also be necessary to have either a hydrator for your `StAttribute` in your `MetadataMap` or there should otherwise be some code implemented to extract the `StAttribute` properties.

You can of course also do this in the fetch method itself, but that is not so pretty.

The object will continue to render as `{}` in case you do not extract or convert the object to something that can be serialized to valid json format (either a `Hal` resource or collection instance, a (json) string or a `JsonSerializable`).